# Check if Integer is Positive or Negative - Objective C

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsinteger

How can I tell in objective-c coding if an integer is positive or negative. I'm doing this so that I can write an "if" statement stating that if this integer is positive then do this, and if its negative do this.

Thanks,

Kevin

Comment: Are you forgetting zero, which is neither positive nor negative?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

```
if (x >= 0)
{
    // do positive stuff
}
else
{
    // do negative stuff
}
```

If you want to treat the `x == 0` case separately (since 0 is neither positive nor negative), then you can do it like this:

```
if (x > 0)
{
    // do positive stuff
}
else if (x == 0)
{
    // do zero stuff
}
else
{
    // do negative stuff
}
```

Comment: Until they discover functions like log(x).

Comment: @BlueRaja - Danny Pflughoeft: well it doesn't have a `-` in front of if, so that's good enough for me. ;-)

Comment: @Deniz: Mathematicians say 0 is a *non-negative* value; but it's not *positive*.

Comment: @BlueRaja - Danny Pflughoeft: if...else statemens evaluate logical expressions as true/false, so for computer "if it is not negative, it is positive".

Comment: @Deniz Acay: Then please do a if(-1) printf("Wow I'm positive"); and fasten your seatbelts.... C takes everything != 0 as true.

Comment: @Deniz Acay: I've never heard of mathematicians accepting 0 as positive (and I used to be a math professor).  Mathematicians use the word "nonnegative" all the time.  They wouldn't need the word if it meant the same thing as "negative".

Comment: Looks like i understood this "non-negative" word as "positive", so thanks for correction :)

Answer (score 3):

Maybe I am missing something and I don't understand the quesiton but isn't this just

```
if(value >= 0)
{
}
else
{
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
-(void) tellTheSign:(int)aNumber
{
   printf("The number is zero!\n");
   int test = 1/aNumber;
   printf("No wait... it is positive!\n");
   int test2 = 1/(aNumber - abs(aNumber));
   printf("Sorry again, it is negative!\n");
}
```

;-)

Seriously though, just use

```
if (x < 0) {
// ...
} else if (x == 0) {
// ...
} else {
// ...
}
```

Don't overdo methods ans properties and helper functions for trivial things.

Answer (score 2):

In Swift

```
var value = 5
if value.signum() == 1 {
   print("Positive value")
} else if value.signum() == -1 {
   print("Negative value")
} else if value.signum() == 0 {
   print("Zero value")
}
```

Comment: What is signum() here .?

Comment: It is function which returns '-1' if this value is negative and '1' if it's positive otherwise, '0'.

Comment: is this native function or you did your self .?

Comment: It's inbuilt function

Comment: can you please in which type this support because I working in objective-c means it Float, Int, Decimal , NSNumber .?

Comment: var direct we can you in swift but objc we need to specify the type first hot you understand that please tell me so I can do this thing Thank You :)

Comment: Find here so help you https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/int64/2886319-signum